# Can't compare Fixnum with nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, while-loop, fixnum

I'm trying to do a bubble sort. I'm passing `bubble_sort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])`, and I get an error message saying: `ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed`. I don't think `arr[i]` or `arr[i + 1]` is `nil`. Please help. This is my code:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)

  until arr == arr.sort
    i = 0
    while i < arr.length
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
      end
      i += 1
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant `while i < (arr.length - 1)` ?

Comment: Yet another good example why you should prefer iterator methods over loops.